# Programmatically download last module version

Tags: 6, updating

Is is possible to download the last version of a module during an hook_update_N() of my custom drupal 6 module?
I am in a case where the module I created needs the last version of CCK and I would like to programmatically download this version and enable it?
Or maybe  is it possible to add the plugin version in the .info dependencies array?

Comment: Drupal 7 has support for versioned dependencies, Drupal 6 does not. So follow what @yvan said. You don't have write permissions for the modules folder (shouldn't have) anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's dangerous process what you're looking for.

What if the user has a older CCK version ?
What if the user patched is CCK ?
What if the latest version of CCK won't works ?

Also, it's not fair to download modules without letting knowing the user what you're doing. From my point of view, the best solution it's to add dependency in the info file and with the hook_init you can check the version of CCK and display a message to as the user download the latest version of CCK.

Comment: OK, thanks for your advice. I think I will use this solution, it's safer.